# Media Queries breakpoint at wrong value

Tags: css, media-queries, breakpoints

I'm working on a responsive website (for the second time), but I'm recently meeting problems... The fact is that all of my media queries breakpoint work fine, but at **wrong values** (135px less than expected), for example:

```
.portfolio {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 400px;
}
.portfolio-item-container {
    float: left;
    height: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}
@media screen and (min-width:320px) {
    .portfolio {
        width: 638px;
    }
    .portfolio-item-container {
        width: 33%;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width:1350px) {
    .portfolio {
        width: 850px;
    }
    .portfolio-item-container {
        width: 25%;
    }
}
```

This short code is taken from my style.css file, the website is a wordpress template and I use Chrome. 
As an example, in this case the breakpoint is at 1215px instead of 1350px as written. I thought it was because of the scrollbar but I removed it and nothing has changed... Then, I tried several words (min-device-width instead of min-width, etc..). Same problem with IE (I did not verify on Mozilla).
I checked my reset css, I have the latest version of normalize.css...

I have already used that structure of media query previously and that worked very well, could it come from an update? I don't know any more where to look, would anybody have an idea?

Thank you beforehand,

Loïc

Comment: That's a strange problem to be having. Are your browser screens zoomed in at all? Also, do you still have the same problem if you switch the px to ems?

Comment: Just had the same issue exactly, I was at 90% zoom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you have:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />`

In the `head` of your page.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer.
Yes, it's already there indeed... Another idea ?

Answer (score 2):

Marked answer didn't resolve the problem.

It is just as mentioned in the comment by  **Scott Harrison** , I did reset the zoom level back to 100% and it worked properly. (it was 110% initially)

Comment: It seems that you need to do this as well as have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />` at the top of your page