# Mediaquery wrong in Chrome?

Tags: css, media-queries

I was testing my media queryies in Chrome and they break at completely different values. What am I doing wrong?

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
      .row .col.col-laptop-4 {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        width: calc(33.33333% - (0.5rem * 2));
        margin-left: 0.5rem;
        margin-right: 0.5rem; }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Without a [mcve] reproducing the issue there's no way anyone can help.

Comment: Checkout the answer on this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26696254/media-queries-firing-at-wrong-width . It may help you out