# Media queries resizing incorrectly

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a rookie problem with some CSS media queries. You see, I already have the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` tag in my header. However, when I run the media query...

```
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) and (max-width: 1281px){

    body{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

It doesn't quite work the way it's supposed to. I am working in a Mac Pro 13 and the query actually executes from 640px to 1025px.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong but I'm sure it's a rookie mistake. If anyone could help me it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this will help: [Media Queries firing at wrong width](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26709884/11700321). `TLDR;` 1. Make sure your browser is at `100%` zoom. 2. Consider using `em` or `rem` instead of `px`. 3. Force the zoom/scale of the browser window with Javascript for more reliable results.

Comment: Thank you @EGC! it was the zoom, I swear this was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `@media all` insted of `@media screen` ?

Comment: Thanks for the help M8, the problem was that I wasn't in 100% Zoom in chrome

Comment: Oh, ok. Happy to hear you found the solution