# Browser breakpoint media query invoked at unintended width

Tags: css, user-interface, sass

Currently, I am attempting to implement browser breakpoints to a web page. I first media query I add to facilitate a break-point for a class of divs only to find that it invoked way off the max-width value (value is 500px, invokes as 124.867px).

I've attempted both resolutions illustrated in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26696254/media-queries-firing-at-wrong-width) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23133609/media-queries-breakpoint-at-wrong-value).

Sass:

```
    .announcement {
        width: 90%;
        height: 40%;
        background: #4C2765;
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 2%;
    }


@media screen and (max-width: 40%) {
    .announcement {
        background: green;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
        <div class="announcements">
                <h3 class="title">Announcements</h3>
                <div class="announcement">
                    <div class="announcement-header">
                        <div class="announcement-title">Empire Institute of Information</div>
                        <div class="announcement-author">by John Doe</div>        
                    </div>
                    <p class="preview-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum gravida blandit leo, dictum venenatis magna vulputate non. Mauris ac pretium mi. Ut laoreet urna in facilisis blandit.
                            Donec nec risus nec orci auctor rutrum ut in felis. Ut euismod augue non est rutrum, et ullamcorper dui. Ut arcu odio, tristique eget pretium porttitor, finibus ac o...
                    </p>
                    <button class="continue-reading">Continue Reading</button>
            </div>
            <div class="announcement">
                    <div class="announcement-header">
                        <div class="announcement-title">Empire Institute of Information</div>
                        <div class="announcement-author">by John Doe</div>        
                    </div>
                    <p class="preview-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum gravida blandit leo, dictum venenatis magna vulputate non. Mauris ac pretium mi. Ut laoreet urna in facilisis blandit.
                            Donec nec risus nec orci auctor rutrum ut in felis. Ut euismod augue non est rutrum, et ullamcorper dui. Ut arcu odio, tristique eget pretium porttitor, finibus ac o...
                    </p>
                    <button class="continue-reading">Continue Reading</button>
            </div>
            <div class="announcement">
                    <div class="announcement-header">
                        <div class="announcement-title">Empire Institute of Information</div>
                        <div class="announcement-author">by John Doe</div>        
                    </div>
                    <p class="preview-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum gravida blandit leo, dictum venenatis magna vulputate non. Mauris ac pretium mi. Ut laoreet urna in facilisis blandit.
                            Donec nec risus nec orci auctor rutrum ut in felis. Ut euismod augue non est rutrum, et ullamcorper dui. Ut arcu odio, tristique eget pretium porttitor, finibus ac o...
                    </p>
                    <button class="continue-reading">Continue Reading</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I expect the background of each announcement div turns green when the width of each div is under 500px.

Answer (score 0):

Belay that, oddly enough a computer restart seemed to of solved the issue.